# ng-model value not available outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an object like this:

```
"styleArr":[
{
    "text":"General Text","default_value":"#d11e1e","scopval":"general"
},
{
    "text":"Accent Color","default_value":"#2ec72e","scopval":"Accent"
},
{
    "text":"Button/Link Hover","default_value":"#2ec72e","scopval":"Button_link"
}]
```

In my template :

```
<div ng-repeat="style in styleArr">
    <span> {{ style.text }} </span>
     <input colorpicker type="text" ng-model="style.scopval"/>
</div>
```

I want to make ng-model value  dynamically.So that I can change the color of text/background color outside from this ng-repeat.

When I try to use ng-model value outside of this ng-repeat it not seems to work for me.

```
 <div class="myclass" ng-style="{'background-color' : general}">This is my first div..</div>
```

Comment: question is not clear. You have the data, so in ng-repeat you should have buttons to get the color instead of having an input. If you have three input after ng-repeat, whats the point of dynamic color retreival.

Comment: What you're asking isn't possible. `ng-model` will store data in `style.scopval`, not in another place.

Comment: where does the var 'general' in ng-style come from?

Comment: In  ng-repeat I have an  inputs.In input click I select colors from color-picker. Also i am creating ng-model dynamically( as above),so I want to use that ng-model value outside of ng-repeat( As in my last line).How can i achieve the same?

Hope it make sense..

Comment: @ alwe  from array above ..

Comment: {'background-color' : general} here "general" is ng-model of input.When it iterate it print ng-model="general". As i am using "style.scopval"...

Comment: You should provide a plunker.

Comment: Where is the variable `general` come from? How is it related to the `styleArr` array above? There isn't a single thing in the last line from the previous part of the code

Comment: "general " is just a value of index "scopval"